# Save JTextField and Selected Radio Button Data To A Text File

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jdialog, fileoutputstream

I've create a GUI in Netbeans to get inputs from the user for certain fields. I don't understand how to save the text from the JTextField and Radio Buttons that are selected to a text file.

I attached the picture below of the user form.

Once "OK" button is pressed, the user gets a dialog to save the file.

Currently, I can save the file to a text file. But nothing appears in the text file. How can I retrieve data from each text field and radio button?

Please help, I've tried a lot of solutions but it has not been working properly.

```
private void buttonOkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try{
        String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the name to be saved", "File Name", 1 );
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(filename+".dat");

        txtFirstName.getText().toString(); //Trying to get text from First Name field.

        writer.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Saved Successfully");

   }catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
}
```

[image: sccreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Between

```
FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(filename+".dat");
```

and

```
writer.close();
```

you should actually write using FileOutputStream's `write` method.

I think that what you want to do is:

```
FileOutputStream writer = null;
    try {

        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(filename+".dat");
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(writer);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(os);
        bw.write(txtFirstName.getText().toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(generafechas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(generafechas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        if(writer!=null)
            try {
                writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(generafechas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

In the above code you can see that the FileOutputStream (conventionally references as fos for lazyness sake) gets wrapped.

There are two families of classes to write files in Java. Readers/Writers and Streams.
Your fos is a stream, so it deals with system specific implementation and writes bytes or integers, meanwhile that the BufferedWritter (bw for lazyness sake) deals with writing Objects, and basic types. With the wrapping we get the best of both worlds, high level handling and low level functionality.

Comment: When I tried that I get an error
***
no suitable method found for write(String)
    method OutputStream.write(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to int)
    method OutputStream.write(byte[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to byte[])
    method FileOutputStream.write(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to int)
    method FileOutputStream.write(byte[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to byte[])
Redundant String.toString()

Comment: It should work now for your specific example. Another way should be a casting to bytes but that is done by the bw internally (painessly, and optimized).